# The method clear() is undefined for the type ShoppingCart

Tags: java, jsp

I am implementing a shopping website through JSP. I have a Java object called `ShoppingCart` and one called Item. In `ShoppingCart` there is a vector which holds Item objects. The idea is when I make a call to the `addItem()` method, I use:-

```
cart.addItem(name, image, price, details);
```

ensuring that the ShoppingCart has **already** been declared:-

```
ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart("file_path_to_file");
```

and the the content of `addItem` is:-

```
public void addItem(String name, String image, String price, String detail) throws IOException  
{  
     items.add(new Item(name, image, price, detail));  
     this.saveMe();  
}
```

where items is the vector. This works **absolutely** fine. I have, however, now created a new method called clear:-

```
public void clear() throws IOException  
{  
    items.clear();  
    this.saveMe();  
}
```

The saveMe method simply saves to an Object file:-

```
private void saveMe() throws IOException  
{  
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.filename);  
     ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)  
     oos.writeObject(this.items);  
     oos.close();  
}
```

When I call the clear method using:-

```
cart.clear();
```

I get the error message:-

> An error occurred at line: 108 in the jsp file: /project/cart.jsp
>       The method clear() is undefined for the type ShoppingCart

Can anybody help with any ideas I can try to resolve this issue?

Comment: It might help to see the *full source code* of `ShoppingCart` class and `/project/cart.jsp`.  It's not obvious that there should be any problems with the code you are giving above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that method was newly added and you get this error, you're apparently still using an old version of the class lacking the method in the classpath. You need to save the source code file, recompile/rebuild the class/project, redeploy the project and restart the server to get the new changes to work.

A bit decent IDE with a bit decent server plugin will do that automagically by the way.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had repeatidly re-compiled the code with no luck, however a server re-boot resolved the problem! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you definitely need to redeploy/restart the webapp/server after changes. Are you using an IDE like Eclipse? You probably need to turn on "automatic publishing" and/or "hot deployment" in the server settings, depending on the server plugin used. Then things will go automagically. Since you're new here, don't forget to mark the most helpful answer accepted. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat on my own machine and Notepad++ for editing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I hope I have done everything I should now on here?

Comment: Notepad++? Right, the hard way. Well done :) Keep coding until you understand from top to bottom how Java web development all works and until it becomes too boring and routinely and then consider switching to an IDE where you basically just have to do Ctrl+S.

Comment: I do use Eclipse for Java projects (where I use multiple classes) but since I only needed to write a couple of classes, I decided to use Notepad++. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try **(re)compiling the code**, deploying it to the server and then opening your .jsp page. And do it every time you make changes in java code, not html code.

**Java is not [interpreted language](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3509911/Term-of-the-Week-Interpreted-Language.htm), but a compiled programming language, whose programs are converted into an executable form before being executed.**

Comment: Thanks guys, I had repeatidly re-compiled the code with no luck, however a server re-boot resolved the problem! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was just fighting a very similar problem in Eclipse.  I deselected "Project->Build Automatically" option and I was clicking "Project->Clean" and cleaning the project, but the error wouldn't go away.  Finally, in the dialog that pops up after clicking "Project->Clean", I deselected the "Start a build immediately" option and did a clean.

It then FINALLY "really" cleaned the project and cleared the error.  Then I started a build and all was fine.

At one point I had commented out the offending line and saved, and **Eclipse was still reporting the error on that line!!!**  I don't know if this is an Eclipse bug or an underlying tool chain bug, but it's definitely not doing the write thing.

This was with Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 and a Java SE 6 target.  Running under Windows XP.