# Access methods from array of interfaces

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem in my code and can't find where. I must be overlooking something.
I'll explain. I have a very simple interface:

```
public interface IMyEntity {

    public String GetName();


}
```

And then i have my class. I want to create a SpinAdapter which uses an array of IMyEntity interface, so i can reuse the spinadapter for all my pojo's which are implementing the interface.

```
public class SpinAdapter<IMyEntity> extends ArrayAdapter<IMyEntity> {


private Context context;
private IMyEntity[] values;

public SpinAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, IMyEntity[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = objects;
}


public int getCount(){
    return values.length;
}

public IMyEntity getItem(int position){
    return values[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView label = new TextView(context);
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label.setText(this.values[position].GetName());
    return label;
}


@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView label = new TextView(context);
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    label.setText(values[position].GetName());

    return label;
}

}
```

the problem i have is on this line:

```
label.setText(values[position].GetName());
```

Here i should get access to the GetName method, but i get an error saying it doesn't exist. I can't use the GetName method of the interface.

What am i doing wrong here?
I hope my question is clear.

Thanks,

Bjorn

Comment: Ok, a dumb question: how do i clean the project. I'm using eclipse. Thx

Comment: Found how to clean, didn't work.

Comment: ok. `this.values` works and `values` without `this` does not work? Maybe you have a variable `values` with a bigger scope that is of a different type. If that is the case, use `getItem()` instead of `values`. otherwise, the problem might be caused by another syntax error. Sometimes eclipse prefers to go nuts

Comment: No, both aren't working :(

Comment: try this instead label.setText(getItem(position).GetName());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it. I deleted the whole class and restarted. Now it works.

Now my class starts with:

```
public class IEntitySpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IMyEntity>
```

and this works.

This doesn't:

```
public class SpinAdapter<IMyEntity> extends ArrayAdapter<IMyEntity>
```

Thanks a lot to everybody who tried to help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces or abstract classes can't be instantiated. You need a class that implements your interface in order to use it.

```
public class MyEntityImpl implements IMyEntity {
     public String GetName() {
         return "" ;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Bjorn Vdkerckhove you're not implementing anything. superclasses get extended, interfaces get implemented. i think you may need to rethink how you're designing your project. why do you need an array of interfaces in the first place?

Comment: Yes i do, i have a class User that does implement the interfaces and serveral others will do too. I'm doing this because i need this adapter for several pojo's. If i don't make one with the interface like now, i have to make a spinadapter for every pojo. Now i can reuse it for several pojo's

Answer (score 0):

You've defined an interface, but no class that implements it. You need a type that implements that interface and then make an array of that type and it will work.

Comment: Adding classes wich implement an interface doesn't make the spinadapterclass without errors

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you are getting? That will help us understand the problem.  Also, edit the code to reflect it's current state.

Comment: GetNmae is underlined in red and when i hover i got this errormessage: The method GetName() is undefined for the type IMyEntity

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the problem is that it doesnt have a constructor, try adding that.

Comment: the spinadapter has a contructor.

Comment: perhaps you should make getName method static?

Comment: Adding static to the interface method gives an error: Illegal modifier for the interface method GetName; only public & abstract are permitted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982327/the-method-clear-is-undefined-for-the-type-shoppingcart maybe this can help