# The method is undefined for the type error

Tags: java

I just don't get why the following lines won't compile:

```
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
tlp.setGenerateOriginalDependencies(true);
```

It was already working before, but now it throws me a

> The method setGenerateOriginalDependencies(boolean) is undefined for
>   the type TreebankLanguagePack

, although `TreebankLanguagePack` is marked as the correct [interface](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreebankLanguagePack.html).
I removed everything and put this minimal class together, but it still doesn't work.

```
import java.util.Collection;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.PennTreebankLanguagePack;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreebankLanguagePack;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TypedDependency;

public class TreebankTest {

    public void test() {
        LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(
                "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz",
                "-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories");
        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
        tlp.setGenerateOriginalDependencies(true);
        GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();

        String[] sent = { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
        Tree parse = lp.apply(Sentence.toWordList(sent));
        GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
        Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
        System.out.println(tdl);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Maybe this method does not exist with the version you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The method clear() is undefined for the type ShoppingCart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982327/the-method-clear-is-undefined-for-the-type-shoppingcart)

Comment: But it was working two days ago and I neither changed the version of the StanfordCoreNLP, nor the Java version, nor my eclipse version.

Comment: Maybe a colleague of you removed the method, look into the jar file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical situation of 
"What you see is NOT what you get" in contrast to the well known WYSIWYG.

You see the method setGenerateOriginalDependencies(boolean) in your src, but the compiler or build system does not see it.
Typical situations:
If the method is in an external library (jar) then either it is not yet built, or you have forgotten to Refresh (eclipse F5) the project. Or you are looking into the wrong project. Or have not saved the file, etc.

Or the method does not exist anymore, a working colleague might have removed it.
In eclipse you can click on the jar file that contains the method and check what eclipse sees.

Comment: Tried all your mentioned possibilities, removed the jar from the Build Path, added it again, still didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Look into the jar, you shoul dbe able to click on it in the eclipse Project Explorer, the jar opens and show all packages. search the packages untill you find the right package and the open it and find the class, then you see wheter the method is missing or has another signature (arguments, boolean in your case.)  2) click on the method in the editor and press F3, will it be found?

Comment: Not there. I still don't get how it possibly has compiled before but that is probably another issue

Comment: At least it is solved why you get that message. Consider upvoting and accepting

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse check your Java buildpath (check your Java JDK/JRE too!), refresh the project (F5) and do Project>Clean of your project.

Comment: unfortunately cleaning did not help as well